# Horizontal scroller full of DIVs? (auto width)

Tags: css

I'm having a great deal of trouble making a horizontal scroller that goes on indefinitely and auto scales (width) to fit the children divs inside of it. It's tough to explain so I've made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/M2b46/

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroller">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.scroller {
    overflow: scroll;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.box-container {
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #0088c4;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

I'd rather not use `box` as it seems buggy. On Webkit based browsers, the blue boxes are not visible for some reason. In Firefox it works exactly as I intended.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: adding position relative to '.box' makes them visible in chrome :)

Answer (score 0):

I got your solution using inline-block:

```
.box-container {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.box {
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #0088c4;
    margin: 1em;

}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M2b46/3/)